# Complexities problems with using big o nation

Tags: c++

Give big O complexities of the following functions :

T(N) = 100N + (N/2) log (N/2) + N/4

T(N) = N log(N^4) + 3 N^2

T(N) = N^2 log N + N^3 + 1000^4

My answer is

first one = o(n)

second one = o(n^2)

third one = o(n^3)

Do I have an any mistake?

Comment: The first one is not linear, but the rest look OK. Why is it tagged C++? This belong to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: In any case, if this is an exercise, make mistakes. You learn by doing stuff yourself. Perfect solutions from strangers on the internet do not advance you at all, and are not available during an exam. Unless it is absolutely crucial because you need the points and you have came up with *something*, go with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one should be Nlog(N). Second and third are correct.